# How to exclude whole folder in jenkins thinbackup plugin settings

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins

i have installed the thinbackup plugin to backup jenkins but as i have left the exclude option empty it is including all the files i never wanted to backup,so now i knew that if i use an expression like

```
^.*\.(log)$
```

it will not include the files having extention as .log but now the situation is i want to exclude a whole folder and struggling to get the regular expression for it.
what i have tried is

```
 /jobs or jobs/*
```

Need help!!

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you can do that with `thinBackup` plugin. However, [Backup Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Backup+Plugin) does what you need and much more. Once you've installed it, just go to `Jenkins > Backup manager` and enable `Configuration files (.xml) only`. Above that you will see a box named `Custom exclusions`. Here you can specify comma- or space-separated list of file/directory names to exclude from backup. See snapshot below:

[image]

You should also check the `Backup content` section shown above to include job workspace, if required. Even that has option to include/exclude files/directories.